# one Image Cropping with For Next loop with muti xy

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, bitmap

## `Hey, Im New with VB.NET`

i'm trying to Crop 1 Image 300,300 to 36 PictureBox 50,50 in list with muti X and Y in For Next loop

`Was like this :`

```
PicBoxs(0).Image = CropBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, 50, 50)
PicBoxs(1).Image = CropBitmap(bmp, 50, 0, 50, 50)    
PicBoxs(2).Image = CropBitmap(bmp, 100, 0, 50, 50)        /* before*/
PicBoxs(3).Image = CropBitmap(bmp, 150, 0, 50, 50)
PicBoxs(4).Image = CropBitmap(bmp, 200, 0, 50, 50)
```

Than i try to code with For loop :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To PicBoxs.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To 250 Step 50
                For k As Integer = 0 To 250 Step 50            /* j for y and k for x*/
                    PicBoxs(i).Image = CropBitmap(bmp, k, j, 50, 50)
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

And i use it for Location too

```
For i As Integer = 0 To PicBoxs.Count -1
            For j As Integer = 50 To 300 Step 50
                For k As Integer = 50 To 300 Step 50
                    PicBoxs(i).Location = New Point(k, j)
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

But i think i am going on to wrong direction. Thank you.

Comment: As written now, for each picture box, your code will cycle through 25 bitmaps, and each will end up with the 250x250 bitmap.  Based on your previous code, I wouldn't expect the outer loop on `i`, instead I would expect `i` to be declared as a freestanding variable which is incremented in the inner loop.

Answer (score -1):

oh ok, i know now

```
Dim picsize As Integer = 75
    Dim zeile As Integer = 4
    Dim spalte As Integer = 4
    For i As Integer = 0 To zeile - 1

        For j As Integer = 0 To spalte - 1

            Dim x As Integer = j * picsize
            Dim y As Integer = i * picsize

            Dim xlo As Integer = j * picsize + 50           'Location + (50,50) fangt nicht mit 0 an.
            Dim ylo As Integer = i * picsize + 50

            Dim index As Integer = i * spalte + j

            Pics(index) = New Bitmap(CropBitmap(bmp, x, y, picsize, picsize))
            PicBoxs(index).Location = New Point(xlo, ylo)

        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**